# Compare two columns and count the result rows

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to count how many times the first and last column of a `sqlite` file are the same for each row in my data set. the data set has 16+ million rows and efficiency is very important.

I have tried:

```
SELECT * FROM tab WHERE [0] = [3]
```

but it doesn't work. probably because it compares the first column of each row with the last column of the same row.

Let's assume this is my data set:

```
0        |1       |2        |3       |
--------------------------------------
2005:67  |ytg     |6utgjgt  |786:09  |
2005:903 |467     |009      |2005:67 |
2005:444 |355     |785      |2005:450|
2005:450 |355     |785      |N/A     |
2005:934 |467     |009      |N/A     |
2005:000 |355     |785      |2005:450|
2005:987 |355     |785      |2005:450|
--------------------------------------
```

the output should be this:

```
0        |1       |2        |3       |4       |
-----------------------------------------------
2005:67  |ytg     |6utgjgt  |786:09  |1       |
2005:450 |355     |785      |N/A     |3       |
2005:934 |467     |009      |N/A     |0       |
-----------------------------------------------
```

the rows whose 4th column were the same as the first column of one of the rows are dropped but were counted. (It is not possible that the 4th column of a row is the same as the first column of more than one row. And the first column's values for each row are identical)
Can everybody please help me? I am a rookie and greatly appreciate some explanation along with the code. Thank you

Comment: Why is `2005:934` included with a zero count, but not others like `2005:444`?

Comment: 2005:444 is dropped because its 4th column is 2005:444, which is equal to the first column of one of the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With NOT EXISTS:

```
select t.*,
  (select count(*) from tab where [3] = t.[0]) [4] 
from tab t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tab 
  where [0] = t.[3]
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cbcctGSsaoht3xDio14ZGM/0).
Results:

```
| 0        | 1   | 2       | 3      | 4   |
| -------- | --- | ------- | ------ | --- |
| 2005:67  | ytg | 6utgjgt | 786:09 | 1   |
| 2005:450 | 355 | 785     | N/A    | 3   |
| 2005:934 | 467 | 009     | N/A    | 0   |
```